# Validating a JSON array in Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have a controller which receives a following POST request:

```
{
  "_token": "csrf token omitted",
  "order": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
}
```

How can I use validators to ensure that elements in `order` are unique, and between 1 and 7? I have tried the following:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'order' => 'required|array',
    'order.*' => 'unique|integer|between:1,7'
]);
```

The first clause is checked, the secound one passes even when the input is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unique` validator keyword is for checking a value's duplicates in database.

You should use custom validator for such situations.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 12):

Using [distinct rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-distinct]):

> **distinct**
>
> When working with arrays, the field under validation must not have any
>   duplicate values.

In your case, it could look like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'order' => 'required|array',
    'order.*' => 'distinct|integer|between:1,7'
]);
```